# Fitting a gaussian for data which is zero everywhere except for a sharp peak in the centre point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

A test code for this type of data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(0,1,20)
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

n = np.size(x)
mean = sum(x*y)/n
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n)

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[max(y),mean,sigma])

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
```

I need to fit lots of data which is just like the y array given above to a Gaussian distribution.

Using the standard gaussian fitting routine using scipy.optimize gives this kind of fit:

[image]

I have tried many different initial values, but cannot get any kind of fit.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could get this data fitted to a Gaussian?

Thanks

Comment: I can see that the question got downvoted here, maybe give it a try here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28311/predict-the-next-players-option-for-betting-based-on-playing-history . I think it is not a pure programming issue so this is why it could have happen.

Comment: @petrch thanks very much!

Comment: I hope that you understand that your fit doesn't make any sense, mathematically speaking.

Comment: I think it actually does make sense, so long as you specify the desired width in some way. Of course, there's probably easier ways for the OP to get what they want than by doing a fit.

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

Your fundamental problem is that you have a severely undetermined fitting problem. Think about it like this: you have three unknowns but only one datapoint. This is akin to solving for `x, y, z` when you only have one equation. Because the height of your gaussian can vary independently of it's width, there are infinitely many distributions, all with different widths that will satisfy the constraints of your fit.

More directly, your `a` and `sigma` parameters can both change the maximum height of the  distribution, which is pretty much the only thing that matters in terms of achieving a good fit (at least once the distribution is centered and fairly narrow). Thus, the fitting routines in Scipy can't figure which to change at any given step.

## The fix

The simplest way to solve the problem is to lock down one of your parameters. You don't need to change your equation, but you do need to make at least one of `a`, `x0`, or `sigma` a constant. The best choice of parameter to fix is probably `x0`, since it's trivial to determine the mean/median/mode of you data by just getting the x coordinate of the one datapoint that is non-zero in y. You'll also need to get a little more clever about how you set your initial guesses. Here's what that looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(0,1,20)
xdiff = x[1] - x[0]
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

# the mean/median/mode all occur at the x coordinate of the one datapoint that is non-zero in y
mean = x[np.argmax(y)]
# sigma should be tiny, since we want a narrow distribution
sigma = xdiff
# the scaling factor should be roughly equal to the "height" of the one datapoint
a = y.max()

def gaus(x,a,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*sigma**2))

bounds = ((1, .015), (20, 1))
popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus, x, y, p0=[a, sigma], maxfev=20000, bounds=bounds)
residual = ((gaus(x,*popt) - y)**2).sum()

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')

xdist = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
plt.plot(xdist,gaus(xdist,*popt),'C0', label='fit distribution')

plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.text(.1,6,"residual: %.6e" % residual)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

## The better fix

You don't need a fit to get the kind of Gaussians you want. You can instead use a simple closed form expression to calculate the parameters that you need, as in the `fitonegauss` function in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gauss(x, a, mean, sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x - mean)**2/(2*sigma**2))

def fitonegauss(x, y, fwhm=None):
    if fwhm is None:
        # determine full width at half maximum from the spacing between the x points
        fwhm = (x[1] - x[0])

    # the mean/median/mode all occur at the x coordinate of the one datapoint that is non-zero in y
    mean = x[np.argmax(y)]

    # solve for sigma in terms of the desired full width at half maximum
    sigma = fwhm/(2*np.sqrt(2*np.log(2)))

    # max(pdf) == 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma). Use that to determine a
    a = y.max() #(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)

    return a, mean, sigma

N = 20
x = np.linspace(0,1,N)
y = np.zeros(N)
y[N//2] = 10

popt = fitonegauss(x, y)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')

xdist = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
plt.plot(xdist,gauss(xdist,*popt),'C0', label='fit distribution')

residual = ((gauss(x,*popt) - y)**2).sum()
plt.plot(x, gauss(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.text(.1,6,"residual: %.6e" % residual)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The advantages of this approach are many. It's far more computationally efficient than any fit could be, it will (for the most part) never fail, and it gives you far more control over the actual width of the distribution that you end up with.

The `fitonegauss` function is set up so that you can directly set the [full width at half maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) of the fitted distribution. If you leave it unset, the code will automatically guess it from the spacing of the x data. This seems to produce reasonable results for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a general "a" parameter, use the proper [normal distribution equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(0,1,20)
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

n = np.size(x)
mean = sum(x*y)/n
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n)

def gaus(x, x0, sigma):
    return 1/np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * sigma**2)*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[mean,sigma])

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
```